# Python3 function to auto adjust decimal value

Tags: python

Is there any function in python3 to auto adjust the decimal value to nearest integer? **like 4.8 to 5  and 4.3 to 4**

Comment: You can `round` numbers with `round`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function. E.g.:

```
>>> round(4.8)
5
>>> round(4.3)
4
```